# Is there a way to search a jSON property that is delimited by comma and return a member id by different property name?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I hope I am explaining this right; as an example, I would like the user_id:***id*** of the matching value: in a returned jSON Array/Object like so...

```
[{"user_id":"1","value":"92056,92054,92018"},{"user_id":"3","value":"92056"},
{"user_id":"2","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, Tennessee"},
{"user_id":"5","value":"California"},
{"user_id":"9","value":"New Mexico, Mississippi, Washington"},
{"user_id":"11","value":"Nevada"},{"user_id":"8","value":"Oklahoma, Louisiana"},
{"user_id":"6","value":"Montana, Oregon"},
{"user_id":"10","value":"Virginia, Illinois"}]
```

For example, if my source is **92056**, I want to get **"1"**, because my user_id for 92056 is "1".

If it is **New Mexico**, I want "**9**" and so on.

This value can consist of several hundred zip codes, so I would like a way to rapidly search for either these values or ***like values*** as this will not ever be duplicated; each user_id will have multiple unique territories or "value".

In case this comes up, I am pulling the data from the database with PHP and passing into a JavaScript variable like so (in Wordpress)...

```
 <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $fullPHP = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id, value FROM " . "refer_cimy_uef_data;");
 ?>
        var phpreps = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($fullPHP); ?>);
        $("#phpoutput").html(phpreps);
```

Comment: Why do you store the `value`s in strings (both in JSON and the database)? An array (an extra table) would be suited better.

Comment: What result do you want when searching for `"Massachusetts"`, as both user 2 and 5 would match that?

Comment: @Bergi I will actually remove those duplicates, they came up due to running a test user, then setting up real user.

Comment: @epascarello I am getting the "New Mexico" at run time and therefore will need to select the id after server-side has already loaded.

Comment: @Shane What does that have to deal with the format? Just saying it makes more sense as an Array that a string that acts like an array.

Comment: @epascarello sorry I was being pulled to another project while working on this. I see what you are saying epascarello and will consider the format when I have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this too hard on yourself. Convert the 'value' property to an array before you send it to the browser client, and just use indexOf on each value array to check if the search query exists. In the following code, the search function at the bottom is very simple. The first part is some client-side conversion code for converting your value properties into proper arrays.

```
//pre-process the data to put 'value' into an array. This would be better done from the server in the initial response.

var input = (function(){

    var arr = [
        {"user_id":"1","value":"92056,92054,92018"},{"user_id":"3","value":"92056"}, 
        {"user_id":"2","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, Tennessee"},
        {"user_id":"5","value":"California"},
        {"user_id":"9","value":"New Mexico, Mississippi, Washington"},
        {"user_id":"11","value":"Nevada"},
        {"user_id":"8","value":"Oklahoma, Louisiana"},
        {"user_id":"6","value":"Montana, Oregon"},
        {"user_id":"10","value":"Virginia, Illinois"}
    ];

    arr.forEach(function(item, index){ //remove extra space from some splitting
        arr[index].value = arr[index].value.replace(/,\s/gi,',').split(',');
    });

    return arr;

})();


var search = function(val){

    for(var i=0, len=input.length; i<len; i++){

        if( input[i].value.indexOf(val) > -1 ) return input[i].user_id;

    }

    return null;

}

console.log( search('New Mexico') );
```

Comment: I believe you are right, I had it as an Array initially and when I did not get the results I was looking for, I ended up looking for jSON options. I will go over your options.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want?:

http://jsfiddle.net/WVqFr/1/

```
var input = [{"user_id":"1","value":"92056,92054,92018"},{"user_id":"3","value":"92056"},
{"user_id":"2","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, Tennessee"},
{"user_id":"5","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, California, Tennessee"},
{"user_id":"9","value":"New Mexico, Mississippi, Washington"},
{"user_id":"11","value":"Nevada"},{"user_id":"8","value":"Oklahoma, Louisiana"},
{"user_id":"6","value":"Montana, Oregon"},
{"user_id":"10","value":"Virginia, Illinois"}];

function searcher(value) {
    for (var item in input) {
        var obj = input[item];
        var val_arr = obj["value"].split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < val_arr.length; i++) {
            var cur = val_arr[i].trim();
            if (value == cur) {
                return obj["user_id"];
            }
        }
    }
}

alert(searcher("New Mexico"));
```

But that's assuming your original input is in the format you specified. It might be easier or faster to search if you used a different format of the input, but that's up to you. Note that `.trim` isn't fully supported by all browsers, so you would need to include a polyfill or implement your own type of "trim". I trim just because it's safest to split by "," but that can leave spaces in some of your arrays but not others. If you know there won't be spaces, in the strings after the commas, then you can ignore the `trim` part. It's just weird in your code because in some places you have something like `"92056,92054,92018"` but in others, you have `"New Mexico, Mississippi, Washington"` - notice the differences in spaces.

Also, if you don't need to use the `trim`, you could remove the inner `for` loop and use `if (val_arr.indexOf(value) > -1) { return obj["user_id"]; }` to see if the split array contains the item you're searching for. But know that older IE versions don't support `Array.indexOf`

Comment: This is looking like what I am looking for, but for some reason my var phpreps is not returning the same as when I do the jQuery output with $("#phpoutput").html(phpreps); So when I replace your var input with the phpreps variable, I don't get the results. I have to play with this for a sec and see if I can come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would you prefer to do the searching server-side or client-side? Will the page need to do multiple searches? If not, server-side might be slightly faster, as less data will be sent across the wire.

Assuming client side (and no libraries loaded), here is one possible solution:

```
var json = [
    {"user_id":"1","value":"92056,92054,92018"},{"user_id":"3","value":"92056"},
    {"user_id":"2","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, Tennessee"},
    {"user_id":"5","value":"Massachusetts, Wyoming, California, Tennessee"},
    {"user_id":"9","value":"New Mexico, Mississippi, Washington"},
    {"user_id":"11","value":"Nevada"},{"user_id":"8","value":"Oklahoma, Louisiana"},
    {"user_id":"6","value":"Montana, Oregon"},
    {"user_id":"10","value":"Virginia, Illinois"}
];

function search(needle) {
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b'+needle+'\\b');
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json[i]['value'].match(reg)) {
            return json[i]["user_id"];
        }
    }
}

alert(search("New Mexico"));​
```

One thing to notice about your sample data: some values appear for multiple user ids (e.g., 'Tennessee') ... this function returns the first one found, but you could easily search the whole list and append to a results array instead of returning.

Comment: that data will be altered to be unique, thanks for pointing it out.